# showing the <li> data in H1 tag on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a `<li>` list in angular

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in data>
<li><a href="">{{x.name}},/a></li> 
</ul>
```

I want what ever `<li>` element I click, the data of the element {{x.name}} should appear in the `<h1>` tag.

```
<h1>{{ anytag}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is, but it's better to use an object, check this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/u7na1n6f/)

JS:

```
$scope.anytag = {};
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in data">
     <li><a href ng-click="anytag.name = x.name">{{x.name}}</a></li> 
</ul>
{{anytag.name}}
```